# Docuasign REST API re-enable e-signature user account

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to write some REST api functions to perform some basic user administration.  I cannot seem to find the secret sauce for re-enabling a closed e-signature user, using either the Admin API or the E-signature API.
I saw a post that said just send the create user POST with the same username and email, but every time I do that, I get a new e-signature user, and not a reactivated closed user.  I would appreciate any tips anyone could share.

Thanks
BL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps try issuing an **Update User** request, which allows you to specify the `userId` of the user account you want to (re)activate. For example:

```
PUT /accounts/{{accountId}}/users

{
    "users": [{
        "userId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "sendActivationEmail": "send"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond.  
I am getting closer.  I was leaving out "sendActivationEmail".  With it included my user moves from "Closed" status to "Pending".   I don't actually want the email to be sent.  Are you aware of a way to enable the user and auto activate it without the activation email?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's possible to reactivate without the email being sent. I'm not familiar with the DocuSign Admin API, but notice there's an operation there called [activateMembership](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/admin-api/reference/users/users/activatemembership). You might try using that, if you haven't already.

Comment: FWIW, I notice that when you use the Admin console (UI) to manually reactivate a user, the activation email is automatically sent to the user (with no apparent ability to disable this email). This makes me suspect that it's likewise not possible to disable the email when reactivating a user via API (since usually API capabilities, at best, *match* UI capabilities --  i.e., it's unusual to be able to do something via API that you can't do manually via the UI).

Comment: Yes, good point.  And this is where I ended up.  I can reenable the user with the e-signature API as you suggested above, and the move the user from "Pending" to "Active" using the admin api; but can't avoid the activation email.  Thanks for taking the time to look at my question and reply.